# run function depending on passed integer in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to run different functions depending on selected level Integer
so if selected level is 1 then runfunc1(), if 2 then runfunc2()...
I know this is possible using if else

```
if levelselected == 1 {
    runfunc1()
} else if levelseletecd == 2 {
    runfunc2()
    // ... and so on
}
```

Is there any better way than this, perhaps something like this

```
runfunc%i(),levelselected // I know its not correct but something similar
```

I dont want to write new code for every level, so any better way?

Comment: You could use a switch statement as well. You can't have a variable as part of the function name.

Comment: yea i know switch but stil will have to write similar code for every level

Comment: Perhaps then have one function and pass levelselected to it

Comment: well thats same isnt it? because i will pass levelselected to this function. and in this function i will have to use switch or if else again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the exact solution you are looking for but this can make it easier :

Declare an array of the desired functions:

```
var levelFunctions: [()->()] = [runfunc1, runfunc2, runfunc3]
```

This syntax declares an array of functions that have zero argument and return nothing. You initialize this array with the required function names and then execute the desired function using the `levelselected` variable:

```
levelFunctions[levelselected]() // Or levelselected-1 if the variable is not zero-based
```

**EDIT:**

As Airspeed Velocity mentioned in the comment and his answer you should make sure the level is in the array bounds.

Comment: Bear in mind if you ever pass a `levelselected` that is greater than the valid functions in the array, it will go bang.

Answer (score 2):

You could have an array or dictionary of functions.  A dictionary might be nicer since the logic for checking if the level is valid is a lot simpler:

```
let funcs = [1: runfunc1, 2: runfunc2]

if let funcToRun = funcs[levelselected] {
    funcToRun()
}
```

However, you won't be able to easily dynamically build a function name from strings and numbers without using `@objc` functionality.

(except in the sense that you could make the key to the dictionary a string of the function name, but you still have to build the dictionary using actual function names determined at compile time)

That said, you can add to the `funcs` variable from elsewhere in the code so it does mean to can "hook up" new levels without changing this dispatching logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
var levelSelected = 0 //

var selector = Selector("runFunc\(levelSelected)")
if self.respondsToSelector(selector) {
    NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector(selector, toTarget: self, withObject: nil)
}
```

Comment: I actually like this one the most since it's very explicit to the reader *AND* it forces some sort of conformity between the two related functions.

Comment: That said, Airspeeds answer is defiantly is more "swifty" and is cleaner.

Comment: It relies on the functions all being methods on the same class (which needs to inherit from `NSObject`).  If you tried it with free functions it won't have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create a function, for example `runFuncFromLevel::Int -> (() -> Void)`. `runFuncFromLevel` return a proper function that you need.

```
func runFuncFromLevel(level: Int) -> () -> Void
{
    switch level
    {
        case 1: return runfunc1
        case 2: return runfunc2
        default: return {}
    }
}
```

Comment: this one works, im think @giorashc's  code is easier